# Weird Firefox Password Manager behavior

Tags: firefox, passwords, browser-addons, lastpass

Few days ago, I click on `Most Visited`, right click `Facebook` and select `Forget about this site`. Of course, all of my history, bookmarks and **6** saved passwords are gone

Yesterday, I installed `LassPass` add-on, and only import Firefox saved password

When I open Firefox, goto Facebook, all of my **6** password are appeared

So, my question is, when I select `Forget about this site`, did Firefox remove my passwords completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparantly its buggy 
http://blogs.computerworld.com/the_forget_this_site_feature_in_firefox_3_5_is_buggy

But this guy has not tested passwords. I just tested password, it has delete all my google.com domain passwords.

BTW: I tested passwords being deleted by exporting them using password exporter extensions

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2848

Comment: Could you recover your deleted passwords using this extension?

Comment: No, they were gone, totally.

Comment: btw I use Firefox 3.6

Comment: Yes, I also use FF 3.6 too. I don't know why my passwords are reappeared again